# Why is it that the surface integral of the flux of a vector field is the same as the surface integral of the vector field itself?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

In other words, this:

[image: definition]

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~archristian/teaching/32b-w17/week-7.pdf

Is this just a definition because what we really care about is how much the vectors are "pushing" through the surface? Or is it an actual equality?

Answer (score 2):

This is just notation: $d\mathbf S = \mathbf n\,dS$. Both sides are computing the flux of $\mathbf F$, i.e., the net amount of $\mathbf F$ pushing outwards across the surface.